# Deducing relations between solutions of a linear second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

I've been stuck with this problem for a couple of days:

> Let $u(t),v(t),w(t)$ solutions to the differential equation $y'''+y=0$, such that $u(0)=1, u'(0)=u''(0)=0$, $v(0)=v''(0)=0, v'(0)=1$ and $w(0)=w'(0)=0, w''(0)=1$. Prove, without solving the equation, that i) $u'(t)=-w(t)$  ii) $v'(t)=w(t)$ iii) $w'(t)=v(t)$ iv) $W[u,v,w]=u^3-v^3+w^3+3uvw=1$ ($W$ is the Wronskian)

None of my tries to prove i) to iii) have been really succesful, since most of them involve solving the equation explicitly, in one way or another. I tried to extract information from the Wronskian since it relates the three solutions and their 1st and 2nd derivatives, however I didn't manage to obtain anything useful in that sense (just that it equals one...)

I'd appreciate any small hint to get started with this problem, but not the answer because I want to try myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the frst question, if we have $u'(t)=-w(t)$ then we also have $u'(t)+w(t)=0$ and you can observe that zero is a solution of the original DE so:
$$(u'(t)+w(t))'''+(u'(t)+w(t))=0$$
Since $w(t)$ is a solution we have $w'''(t)+w(t)=0$ we are left with:
$$u''''(t)+u'(t)=0$$
Integrate:
$$u'''(t)+u(t)=C$$
Since $u(t)$ is a solution of the DE we must have the constant $C=0$
$$u'''(0)+u(0)=0$$
We are given $u(0)=1$ so that we must have $u'''(0)=-1$
This is the case since:
$$u'(t)=-w(t) \implies u'''(0)=-w''(0)=-1$$
Sine it's given that $w''(0)=1$.